# Jenkins Pipeline "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline that is ran via a webhook from GitLab whenever a change is pushed to my repo. In Jenkins, I have the following trigger option selected:

[image: GitLab Push Trigger]

Is there a way for me to add this trigger to my Jenkins declarative pipeline, if so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are using the Gitlab plugin for jenkins?
if so this link should be of help https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#declarative-pipeline-jobs

Comment: This is 100% exactly what I needed!

Comment: In addition to this, you should be able to use Jenkins' "Pipeline Syntax" tool to generate the declarative code from the web UI configuration.

Comment: The implementation/support for gitlab triggers inside the Declarative Directive Generator is thing o' beauty.